# Graphics rendering operation on esri

Tags: esri, arcgis-js-api

Does someone knows why graphics objects such as polygon, point, picture marker and etc are rendering 
from scratch while zooming or moving esri map?

For example, in the following link the brackets disappears and rendering from the start in each zoom change or map move: [example](http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/samples/renderer_class_breaks/).

Thanks in advance,

Gal

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the graphics redraw from scratch when panning and zooming because a graphics layer has been added to the map control.

```
GraLay.SelectedFeature = new ags.GraphicsLayer();
map.addLayer(GraLay.SelectedFeature);
```

Comment: Hi Lambert, thanks for your answer. Do you know how to avoid this effect? And to get a continuous effect? Such as in openlayers? For example see this [link](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.0/examples/polygon-styles.html?q=geojson)

Comment: galbuy - You will have to use the latest version of the ESRI JavaScript API 4.0 to get the smooth graphic transition that you want.  See link here: [API 4.0](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/beta/sample-code/get-started-graphics/index.html)